# Reading WebSphere MQ activity log file

Tags: logging, android-activity, ibm-mq

Please tell me how do i read the MQ activity logs ? Which inside the QManger  folder.Thats format is human unreadable

Answer (score 9):

Please confirm which directory and the filename of the log you are trying to read.  Active log files such as S0000001.LOG are not human readable. They are used internally by the queue manager.

The logs most often used to administer a queue manager are the error logs such as AMQERR01.LOG which are found in the subdirectory under qmgrs/*QMGRNAME*/errors directory.

If you truly need to see some info stored in the active log files, you can use the dmpmqlog command to dump a formatted version.  Refer to the knowledge center: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083170_.htm

Comment: Thank you for response . Yes i want to check Qmangers transaction stuffs

Answer (score 0):

use **strings**  to read the MQ queue manager logs

Comment: You should expand on you post some.  For example, does this apply to Unix/Linux, Windows or both?  Can you give an example of how exactly to run the command.  Note the answer from @ValerieLampkin already provides info on a IBM utility that can actually read and format the logs, your suggestion will only show you any readable strings that fall in the file.